# Get-AzTableRow for rows with boolean value?

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

I haven't been able to get a query to work with a filter based on a Boolean column value and none of the examples use a Boolean column.

E.g., something like this should work, no?

```
Get-AzTableRow -table $storageTable -ColumnName ColumnA -Value $false -operator Equal
```

Where ColumnA is a Boolean in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a filter with `GenerateFilterConditionForBool` like this:

```
[string]$booleanFilter = `
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForBool("ColumnA",`
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal, $false)

Get-AzTableRow -table $storageTable -ColumnName ColumnA -Filter $booleanFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Solved using `CustomFilter` instead:

```
Get-AzTableRow -table $storageTable -CustomFilter "(ColumnA eq false)"
```